# why this fragment shader run on some sumsung device has lot of red hot points

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader

```
public static final String LOOKUP_FRAGMENT_SHADER = "varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate;\n" +
        " varying highp vec2 textureCoordinate2; // TODO: This is not used\n" +
        " \n" +
        " uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture;\n" +
        " uniform sampler2D inputImageTexture2; // lookup texture\n" +
        " \n" +
        " void main()\n" +
        " {\n" +
        "     lowp vec4 textureColor = texture2D(inputImageTexture, textureCoordinate);\n" +
        "     \n" +
        "     mediump float blueColor = textureColor.b * 63.0;\n" +
        "     \n" +
        "     mediump vec2 quad1;\n" +
        "     quad1.y = floor(blueColor/ 8.0);\n" +
        "     //quad1.y = floor(floor(blueColor) / 8.0);\n" +
        "     quad1.x = floor(blueColor) - (quad1.y * 8.0);\n" +
        "     \n" +
        "     mediump vec2 quad2;\n" +
        "     quad2.y = floor(ceil(blueColor) / 7.999);\n" +
        "     quad2.x = ceil(blueColor) - (quad2.y * 8.0);\n" +
        "     \n" +
        "     highp vec2 texPos1;\n" +
        "     texPos1.x = (quad1.x * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.r);\n" +
        "     texPos1.y = (quad1.y * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.g);\n" +
        "     \n" +
        "     highp vec2 texPos2;\n" +
        "     texPos2.x = (quad2.x * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.r);\n" +
        "     texPos2.y = (quad2.y * 0.125) + 0.5/512.0 + ((0.125 - 1.0/512.0) * textureColor.g);\n" +
        "     \n" +
        "     lowp vec4 newColor1 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, texPos1);\n" +
        "     lowp vec4 newColor2 = texture2D(inputImageTexture2, texPos2);\n" +
        "     \n" +
        "     lowp float mixPercent=fract(blueColor);\n" +
        "     lowp vec4 newColor = mix(newColor1, newColor2, mixPercent);\n" +
        "     gl_FragColor = vec4(newColor.rgb, textureColor.w);\n" +
        " }";
```

when i use " quad1.y = floor(blueColor/ 8.0);" replace "quad1.y = floor(floor(blueColor) / 8.0)",everything is ok,no red points.

I've write a demo use java code ,they always have same result..i do not know why they have different effect in fragment shader.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling wrapping on your inputImageTexture2 texture, perhaps?

i.e. call these functions when the inputImageTexture2 texture is bound.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Comment: I've done this when load texture..only some samsung low configuration device calculate them different...